# If for $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ , we define $v(t)=u(x+th) $ $v: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ $\Rightarrow^?$ $v \in L^2((0,1))$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I have a function $u(x) \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ($n \geq 2$). Suppose we define another function $v$ as $$v:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} $$ $$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad  \ t \to u(x+th)$$ where $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is fixed.

> Does $v $ belong to $L^2((0,1))$?

I think the answer should be yes considering the fact that (Let's say $n=2$) $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} u \ dx= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}}u \ dx_1 dx_2$, so both integrals over $\mathbb{R}$ are finite and: $$\int_{(0,1)}u\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}u$$

But the "direction" of $h$ bothers me.

Comment: So what is $x$? Is it fixed?

Comment: @JohnMa $x$ is the variable for $u$.

Comment: Sorry, but for $v$, of course, you set it fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this counterexample. Let $u:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ s.t.
$$
u(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y}} & (x,y)\in [0,1]\times[0,1]\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

We can show this function is in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ (according to [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E1+%5Cint_0%5E1+1%2F(x%5E2%2By)+dxdy), 
$$
\int \vert u(x,y)\vert^2 dxdy=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2+y}dxdy \approx 2.26394
$$
).
However, $v(t)=u(t,0)\notin L^2([0,1])$, since $\int_0^1 v(t)^2dt=\int_0^1\frac{1}{t}dt$ is not convergent.

Comment: Or even simpler: $$u(x, y) = \begin{cases} \infty &\text{if } y = 0, x\in [0,1] \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you both. I hadn't considered the trick of using a null measure set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is not of null measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For the sake of curiosity, Could the result still be true if we add the hypotesis $u$ continuous?

Comment: @D1X If $u$ is continuous, so is $v$. Since $[0,1]$ is bounded, so is $v$. Hence, in this case, $v\in L^2([0,1])$.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that $v$ is not even well-defined. Indeed, the function $u$ and
$$\tilde u(y) = u(y) + \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } y = x + t \, h \text{ for some } t \in [0,1]\\ 0 & \text{else}\end{cases}$$
belong to the same equivalence class in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$. However, both functions would be mapped to a different $v$.

Comment: I don't see how that's a problem. I am defining $v$ from $u$.

Comment: But $\tilde u = u$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ - they only differ on a set of measure zero. And if you define $v$ by using the representative $u$ you get another function than defining it via the representative $\tilde u$.